# How to ignore async let throws error when save response in tuple?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-concurrency

i have a code like this:

```swift
Task {
    async let configsReq = self.interactor.getConfigs()
    async let optionsReq = self.interactor.getOptions()
    async let updateStateReq = self.interactor.getAppUpdateState()
    async let contactsReq = self.interactor.getContactOptions()

    var config: Config?
    var options: AvailableOptions?
    var updateState: UpdateType?
    var contacts: ContactOptions?

    do {
        config = try await configsReq
    } catch {
        config = nil
    }

    do {
        options = try await optionsReq
    } catch {
        options = nil
    }

    do {
        updateState = try await updateStateReq
    } catch {
        updateState = nil
    }

    do {
        contacts = try await contactsReq
    } catch {
        contacts = nil
    }

    self.goToNextPage()
}
```

in this case it does not matter for me that the requests get correct response or throws error. i don't want to block user to get correct response.
And also I want to make sure that all my requests are answered (correct or error response) to take the user to the next page

how can i write these codes cleaner and better with new swift concurrency?
i tried like this (but i could not get match error to each related request):

```swift
Task {
    async let configs = self.interactor.getConfigs()
    async let options = self.interactor.getOptions()
    async let updateState = self.interactor.getAppUpdateState()
    async let contacts = self.interactor.getContactOptions()

    do {
        let array = try await [configs, options, updateState, contacts]
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say that you want to “match error to each related request”, are you saying that you want `goToNextPage` needs to know what error is associated with which request, or that just for debugging purposes you want to know?

Comment: Also, in the above examples, you are saving results in local variables that are never passed to `goToNextPage` (and thus you are discarding not only errors, but values, too). I assume this was something introduced in the preparation of the question. Can we assume that you really will be passing these results to `goToNextPage` as parameters to the method? (I guess you could save them in local properties, too, but that introduces other issues.)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to:

- “match error to each related request”, but that
- you want to proceed regardless of success or failure, as it “does not matter for me that the requests get correct response or throws error”.

If that is the pattern you are looking for, I might suggest using `Task` [`result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/result):

```swift
async let configsReq  = Task { try await interactor.getConfigs() }
async let optionsReq  = Task { try await interactor.getOptions() }
async let stateReq    = Task { try await interactor.getAppUpdateState() }
async let contactsReq = Task { try await interactor.getContactOptions() }

let config   = await configsReq.result
let options  = await optionsReq.result
let state    = await stateReq.result
let contacts = await contactsReq.result

goToNextPage(config: config, options: options, state: state, contacts: contacts)
```

Or, more concisely:

```swift
async let configs  = Task { try await interactor.getConfigs() }
async let options  = Task { try await interactor.getOptions() }
async let state    = Task { try await interactor.getAppUpdateState() }
async let contacts = Task { try await interactor.getContactOptions() }

await goToNextPage(config: configs.result, options: options.result, state: state.result, contacts: contacts.result)
```

Where `goToNextPage` might be defined as:

```swift
func goToNextPage(
    config:   Result<Config, Error>,
    options:  Result<AvailableOptions, Error>,
    state:    Result<UpdateType, Error>,
    contacts: Result<ContactOptions, Error>
) { … }
```

That way, `goToNextPage` can look at the `.success` or `.failure` for each, to retrieve either the value or error associated with each of the four requests.

Needless to say, you also could have four properties for these four requests, and then `goToNextPage` could refer to those, rather than taking them as parameters to the method. It’s functionally the same thing, but you have to decide either local vars that are passed to the next method or update properties that are accessed by the next method.

---

You asked:

> … if we don't want to use `Result` anymore, how can do that?

Yes, we do not use `Result` very much, anymore, as that was historically a pattern for returning either value or error in traditional asynchronous patterns, and nowadays we `try` a series of tasks, catch thrown errors, but generally early exit once one of them fails.

But if you really want to capture the success and failure for each of the four concurrent requests, then `Result` encapsulates that quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a little helper that helps wrap the error into a `Result`:

```
extension Result {
    init(asyncCatching block: () async throws -> Success) async where Failure == Error {
        do {
            self = .success(try await block())
        } catch {
            self = .failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In case of errors, you even get the `Error` object for each `getXXX` method, rather than just a `nil`. Of course, if you really just want a `nil`, you can write a helper that returns optionals instead.

```
// this is essentially like refactoring out the repeated parts of your first code
func asyncCatchWithNil<Result>(function: () async throws -> Result) async -> Result? {
    do {
        return try await function()
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
Task {
    async let configs = Result(asyncCatching: self.interactor.getConfigs)
    async let options = Result(asyncCatching: self.interactor.getOptions)
    async let updateState = Result(asyncCatching: self.interactor.getAppUpdateState)
    async let contacts = Result(asyncCatching: self.interactor.getContactOptions)
    /* or
    async let configs = asyncCatchWithNil(function: self.interactor.getConfigs)
    async let options = asyncCatchWithNil(function: self.interactor.getOptions)
    async let updateState = asyncCatchWithNil(function: self.interactor.getAppUpdateState)
    async let contacts = asyncCatchWithNil(function: self.interactor.getContactOptions)
    */

    let (configsResult, optionsResult, updateStateResult, contactsResult) 
        = await (configs, options, updateState, contacts)

    // you can inspect each result here if you'd like
    
    self.goToNextPage()
}
```

The idea here is that you get a type that can contain both the response *and* error at the point of `async let`, rather than catching the error later.

Comment: it's great answer but if we don't want to use Result any more, how can do that?

Comment: @Sajjad Use the `asyncCatchWithNil` function I showed instead. Just replace `Result(…)` with a call to that instead. Then you’d get optionals instead.